# Formatting timestamps during autumn DST switchover

Tags: python, datetime

I've written code that 99.x% of the time does the same thing as

```py
def format(timestamp: datetime) -> str:
    return timestamp.strftime("%X")
```

but follows the German "Sommerzeitverordnung" ("daylight savings time decree") during the hour before and after the autumn switchover.

> Die Stunde von 2 Uhr bis 3 Uhr erscheint dabei zweimal. Die erste Stunde (von 2 Uhr bis 3
> Uhr mitteleuropäischer Sommerzeit) wird mit 2A und die zweite Stunde (von 2 Uhr bis 3 Uhr mitteleuropäischer
> Zeit) mit 2B bezeichnet.

(Sommerzeitverordnung, §2, Abs. 2, Satz 3-4)

Translation (by google translate with minor fixes by me)

> The hour from 2 a.m. to 3 a.m. appears twice. The first hour (from 2 a.m. to 3 a.m.
> Central European summer time) becomes 2A and the second hour (from 2 a.m. to 3 a.m. Central European
> time) is denoted by 2B.

I've written the following pytests

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

from timezone_formatting import format


def test_timestamp_without_marker() -> None:
    assert "01:59:59" == format(datetime(
        year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=1, minute=59, second=59,
        tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')))
    assert "03:00:00" == format(datetime(
        year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=3, minute=0, second=0,
        tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')))


def test_timestamp_during_last_hour_before_switchover() -> None:
    assert "02A:00:00" == format(datetime(
        year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=2, minute=0, second=0,
        fold=0,
        tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')))
    assert "02A:59:59" == format(datetime(
        year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=2, minute=59, second=59,
        fold=0,
        tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')))


def test_timestamp_during_first_hour_after_switchover() -> None:
    assert "02B:00:00" == format(datetime(
        year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=2, minute=0, second=0,
        fold=1,
        tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')))
    assert "02B:59:59" == format(datetime(
        year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=2, minute=59, second=59,
        fold=1,
        tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')))
```

and the following code, which passes the tests:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


utc = timezone.utc
germany = ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")

offset = timedelta(hours=1)


def switchover_letter(timestamp: datetime) -> str:
    """
    Returns "A" if timestamp is in the last hour of daylight savings time.
    Returns "B" if timestamp is in the first hour of standard time.
    Else returns an empty string
    """
    utc_timestamp = timestamp.astimezone(utc)

    if (utc_timestamp + offset).astimezone(germany).hour == timestamp.hour:
        return "A"
    if (utc_timestamp - offset).astimezone(germany).hour == timestamp.hour:
        return "B"

    return ""


def format(timestamp: datetime) -> str:
    return (
        timestamp.strftime("%H")
        + switchover_letter(timestamp)
        + timestamp.strftime(":%M:%S")
    )
```

But, there are two things that kind of raise red flags for me:

- Calling strftime twice on the same timestamp and inserting my own formatting in between seems **wrong**. Is there a format specifier for strftime I have missed, or is there something else I could do to make this less icky?
- Manually doing time manipulation in switchover_letter. I'm reasonably sure that my code is correct, but is it really? Is there a way to do this less manually? Note that doing this without the roundtrip to UTC doesn't work, [because "timezone aware timestamp + offset" uses wall time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804395/adding-timedelta-to-local-datetime-unexpected-behaviour-accross-dst-shift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall this is well-written.

Don't call a function `format`; that shadows a built-in.

> Calling `strftime` twice on the same timestamp and inserting my own formatting in between seems wrong. Is there a format specifier for `strftime` I have missed, or is there something else I could do to make this less icky?

Your instincts are correct; prefer instead:

```
def daylight_savings_format(timestamp: datetime) -> str:
    return '{0:%H}{1}:{0:%M:%S}'.format(
        timestamp, switchover_letter(timestamp)
    )
```

Or do two passes where you first format a datetime-field string with your middle character and then pass that to `strftime`, as in

```py
def daylight_savings_format(timestamp: datetime) -> str:
    fmt = f'%H{switchover_letter(timestamp)}:%M:%S'
    return timestamp.strftime(fmt)
```

I have a weak preference for the former.